# How to find number of rows and columns in a 2D array in C (any simpler way than this?)

Tags: c

I have this code fragment:

```
    char result[10][7] = {
        {'1', 'X', '2', 'X', '2', '1', '1'},
        {'X', '1', '1', '2', '2', '1', '1'},
        {'X', '1', '1', '2', '2', '1', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', '2', 'X', '2', '2', '2'},
        {'1', 'X', '1', 'X', '1', 'X', '2'},
        {'1', 'X', '2', 'X', '2', '1', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', '2', '2', '1', 'X', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', '2', 'X', '2', '1', 'X'},
        {'1', '1', '1', 'X', '2', '2', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', '2', 'X', '2', '1', '1'}

    };

    int row = sizeof(result) / sizeof(result[0]);
    int column = sizeof(result) / row;

    printf("Number of rows: %d\n", row);
    printf("Number of columns: %d\n", column);
```

is there any prebuilt function or anything like that especially for calculating number of columns? I am asking this because we get the number of total elements as `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int)` and need another division, but I want to compute the number of columns directly.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here. `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)` computes the number of items in an array. This calculation happens at compile time and doesn't lead to any calculation overhead in your run-time executable. It's even fairly common to make a function-like macro like `#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr))`.

Comment: You already *told* it how many rows and columns. If you use constants for those, they can have a single point of definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To compute the number of elements of any defined array, you can use the `sizeof` operator regardless of the array element type:

```
some_type A[] = { ... };
size_t length = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
```

For your 2D array definition, you can get the number of columns as the length of array `result[0]`.

Here is a modified version of your code to get the lengths of both dimensions directly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char result[][7] = {
        {'1', 'X', '2', 'X', '2', '1', '1'},
        {'X', '1', '1', '2', '2', '1', '1'},
        {'X', '1', '1', '2', '2', '1', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', '2', 'X', '2', '2', '2'},
        {'1', 'X', '1', 'X', '1', 'X', '2'},
        {'1', 'X', '2', 'X', '2', '1', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', '2', '2', '1', 'X', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', '2', 'X', '2', '1', 'X'},
        {'1', '1', '1', 'X', '2', '2', '1'},
        {'1', 'X', '2', 'X', '2', '1', '1'},
    };

    size_t rows = sizeof(result) / sizeof(result[0]);
    size_t cols = sizeof(result[0]) / sizeof(result[0][0]);

    printf("Number of rows: %zu\n", rows);
    printf("Number of columns: %zu\n", cols);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that the expressions for `row` and `column` in your code are computed at compile time by optimizing compilers.

Answer (score -1):

There is no built-in function specifically for calculating the number of columns in a two-dimensional array in C. The way it is typically done is by using the sizeof operator to determine the size of the array and then dividing it by the size of one of its rows or one of its elements.

As you pointed out, in your code snippet, you have calculated the number of rows correctly by dividing the size of the entire array by the size of one row. To calculate the number of columns, you can use the same method by dividing the size of the entire array by the size of one element, which in this case is a char.

In your case, you have already defined the number of columns, so you can just use it instead of calculating it.

int column = sizeof(result[0]) / sizeof(char);

It should be noted that if your array is not a rectangular array, meaning the number of columns is not the same for all rows, then you would need to calculate the number of columns for each row individually and not using the sizeof operator.

Comment: Rather than using the array element type `char` explicitly, use the array element as argument to `sizeof`: `size_t column = sizeof(result[0]) / sizeof(result[0][0]);`. This will avoid a hard to find bug if the array element type ever changes in a code revision or if the code is copy+pasted in a different context.

Comment: *you would need to calculate the number of columns for each row individually and not using the sizeof operator*: I'm afraid this is incorrect: if the array is a 2D array, all rows have the same length by definition